# Activity gets stuck in Initial state

Tags: moryx

**Application Context**
I have an activity similar to this one

```cs
[ActivityResults(typeof(DefaultActivityResult))]
public class SomeActivity : Activity<CablePullingParameters>, IInstanceModificationActivity
{
    public override ProcessRequirement ProcessRequirement => ProcessRequirement.Required;

    public override ICapabilities RequiredCapabilities => new SomeCapabilities();

    public IIdentity InstanceIdentity { get ; set ; }
    public InstanceModificationType ModificationType { get; set; } = InstanceModificationType.Created;

    protected override ActivityResult CreateFailureResult()
    {
        return ActivityResult.Create(DefaultActivityResult.Failed);
    }

    protected override ActivityResult CreateResult(long resultNumber)
    {
        return ActivityResult.Create((DefaultActivityResult)resultNumber);
    }
}
```

and a Cell that publishes a ReadyToWork

```
[ResourceRegistration]
public class SomeCell : Cell
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        base.OnInitialize();
        Capabilities = new SomeCapabilities();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Session> ControlSystemAttached()
    {
        yield return Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Push);
    }

    public override void StartActivity(ActivityStart activityStart)
    {
        var _currentSession = activityStart;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Session> ControlSystemDetached() { return null; }

    public override void SequenceCompleted(SequenceCompleted completed) { }
}
```

**Problem Description**
When I run a workplan with only the `SomeActivity` in it, I see that the process starts and the activity gets into the `Initial` state. Here it gets stuck, showing no progress at all. I can see no indicator why this happens  or how I could get the activity to be started.

**What I already checked:**

- `SomeCell` gets other activities (like setups, which I excluded from the example)
- `SomeCell` does have the correct `SomeCapabilities`
- There is no notification indicating that the `SomeActivity` could not be assigned